# How can I create beautiful, random, abstract images?

Tags: procedural-generation, graphic-effects

To generate random, beautiful, abstract images – which algorithms are not too complex and give good results?

Comment: That is a very broad and ambiguous question. Can you share some example images?

Comment: I suppose it's an interesting experiment. Ask a broad vague question, then leave it alone and don't follow up for 9+ hours. Just let everyone guess at what you mean and see what comes out. Like seeing what grows on those leftovers in the back of the fridge. (Ah ha, that last bit might actually answer your question).

Comment: @Byte56, It is not like that, I asked the best question I could, and this is not the first one. The problem is quite broad itself.. Quality of the answers support my thesis.

Comment: You give yourself too much credit. The quality of these answers shows the quality of the community. The quality of this question is reflected in its score.

Comment: I disagree. Score of the question is result of social mechanisms, where group is likely to join attacking and excluding one of members. Number of favourites is one confirmation of this point of view.

Comment: GameCoder again you overestimate. People favorite because they want to come back to *the answers* not the question. We're in agreement that the question spawned some great answers, but that doesn't mean it was a good question, it just means we have a good community. Are you disagreeing with me that your question was broad and ambiguous? Down voting is not an attack or exclusion, it's a way to show the quality of a post. It's not personal against the poster.

Comment: So down voting *and* making it a favorite is a perfect example of a bad question with good answers.

Comment: :) Lets focus on the answers then. IMO, if I obtained good answers, I did a good question. If it would be an evolution that would rate me, I would get good fitness ;)

Comment: We'll just agree to disagree. Please try to make your future questions a better fit for this site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) if you're not sure what a good question is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An approach I saw once was to generate a random mathematical function mapping x, y to a color.  It was represented as a parse tree, built top-down, where each node was randomly chosen to be +, -, *, /, a trigonometric function, a constant color, or a variable (x or y); then any required subtree(s) were recursively generated.  Then you evaluate the function for each pixel to get the image.  It produced an interesting mix of structure (repeated elements, broken symmetries, etc.) and randomness.

Here are a couple examples.  These use a slightly different algorithm than what I just described: they generate three separate random functions, one each for R, G, and B.  Unfortunately the result tends to look like three independent images composited, which is why I suggested just using one random vector-valued function.

EDIT: I wrote up a slightly more detailed version of this answer as a [blog post](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/07/15/generating-abstract-images-with-random-functions/), including a Python implementation of the algorithm.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds pretty neat. Happen to have any examples of results?

Comment: @Byte56 Not on this computer; when I get home I can post a couple.

Comment: How did you draw the pixels? I am looking for a simple menthod to do off-screen drawing in mobile environment.

Comment: @GameCoder I just created an array to store the pixel values and looped over 'em to evaluate the function.

Comment: Might http://www.karlsims.com/papers/siggraph91.html be what you were thinking of?

Comment: @AntonMårtensson That's a cool technique, but from a quick skim of the paper it looks quite different from what I described here.  (You should write a short summary of it and post it as another answer to this question! :))

Answer (score 12):

Using a cellular automata for simulation of a relaxion-diffusion equation might be right up your lines - the equations aren't really all that complex and the results are pretty striking.  Have a look at http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/reaction_diffusion/reaction_diffusion.html for some of the first papers on applying the results to computer graphics; http://www.sci.utah.edu/~allen/reaction-diffusion.html has some other fine examples, including for instance:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Comment gone answer, as per Nathan Reed's suggestion :)

Karl Sims did some work about 20 years ago producing (among other things) wonderful abstract images, [see here for details](http://karlsims.com/papers/siggraph91.html). Scroll about halfway down to see some beautiful samples.

Basically a syntax tree is created, mapping X and Y coordinates to colors, and then genetic programming was applied using exhibition (IIRC) visitors for scoring.

In the actual implementation described, the syntax trees are expressed and evaluated using Lisp. Section 4.1 in the linked paper lists the available functions, which are about half normal mathematical functions and half image processing/generation functions such as blur or bw-noise.

Comment: I remember that paper!  His 3d structures (built by mutating surface parameters, IIRC) were even more astonishing.  These days it seems like a lot of artists are using Processing for similar ideas.  +1 just for someone else remembering all that early-90s SIGGRAPH work. :-)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Well of course :D The old SIGGRAPH papers tend to be wonderful sources of material and inspiration for hobby projects, or just interesting in general.